# htaccess redirect to subdirectory and hide it

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've been struggling with this for a while.

My app structure is as follows:

```
- webroot
    - app
      - index.php
      - .htaccess
```

I want that when someones goes to the webroot `www.example.com` to be redirected to the app folder where the app starts. However I want the URL to be `www.example.com`, not `www.example.com/app/`.

I suppose I'll need two htaccess? One in webroot and one in app.

Currently the `/app/.htaccess` looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

This hides the `.index.php` file from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

create one more .htaccess in the webroot with this lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !^app/ /app%{REQUEST_URI}
```